# Create a Dictionary with List Values through a Dict Comprehension?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, dictionary-comprehension

Let's say I have

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5]
```

I'm trying to create a dictionary where

```
dictObj = { (key,[]) for key in a}
```

but I'm getting an unhashable type error. This seems weird to me since it's fine if values are lists right? I was wondering if anyone could tell me the correct syntax for creating a hash table where all the keys are the elements in a and each key points to an empty array.

Comment: That's not how you do a dictionary comprehension.

Comment: Whats your expected output?

Comment: And your title should say dictionary comprehension, not list comprehension

Comment: @VivekKalyanarangan. That's stated quite clearly in the question.

Comment: Why not just use `collections.defaultdict(list)`?

Comment: @RoadRunner https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lawUkmD3i9I&feature=youtu.be&t=4

Answer (score 5):

The key and value in a dictionary comprehension aren't represented as a tuple, they are simply separated by a `:`

```
dictObj = {key:[] for key in a}
```

Answer (score 3):

Do you mean this?

```
dictObj = { key:[] for key in a}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to keep what you have, you need to wrap `dict()` instead of curly brackets:

```
dict((key, []) for key in a)
```

which is the same as what others have given, but just slightly different syntax.

Aditionally, if you want to initialize your dictionary with empty lists, you should have a look at [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict), which initializes your keys to any type you choose. This prevents you from having to do this yourself.

Here is an example usage:

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(list)
a = [1,2,3,4,5]

for key in a:
    print(key, ':', d[key])
```

Which prints out an initialized list for each item, as outputted below:

```
1 : []
2 : []
3 : []
4 : []
5 : []
```

Then you could add items to each key from here.